# flutter - how do you convert a Map<dynamic.dynamic> to List<String>

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, future

I am running a Firebase query in a future builder and retrieving the children.

The snapshot comes back fine, but i would like to add the data into a List

i am tying to do the following:

```
litems.clear();

                                    Map<dynamic, String> values = snapshot.data.value;
                                    values.forEach((key, values) {
                                      litems.add(values);
                                    });
```

`litems` is my List which i would like to use in a dropdown list.

in my dropdown list i have:

```
items: litems.map((String value) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: new Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
```

the error i get in my first part is that Map cannot be assigned to a List

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is, but using a for loop inside a list declaration is cleaner and might solve it :

```
item : [
    for(var value in litems.values)
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
        );
]
```

*You need the min SDK version in your pubspec.yaml to be >=2.6.0*

Comment: the issue isnt on grt he dropdown, I get the error when trying to populate items with the snapshots from firebase. I get told that the type is mismatched. The snapshot is Map<dynamic,dynamic> while the list is List<String>. Even when I replace the dropdown list with static items

Comment: Then maybe try `snapshot.value` or `litems.add(values.value);`. You have to match the way your database is structured. You can also run in debug mode and set a breaking point after you retrieve the snapshot to see exactly what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to add all values as a single entry rather than a specific value.

```
Map<dynamic, String> values = snapshot.data.value;
values.forEach((key, values) {
    litems.add(values);
});
```

You might try

```
Map<dynamic, String> values = snapshot.data.value;
values.forEach((value) {
    litems.add(value);
});
```

or

```
values.forEach((key, values) {
    litems.add(values[key]);
});
```

Comment: I still get an error in the Futurebuilder which says List<String> is not a subtype of Map <dynamic,dynamic> . In my Firebase snapshot, i am doing it as a DocumentSnapshot and using the property `.once()` is this correct?

Comment: and also when trying to do litems.add(values[key]), it is expecting me to enter an integer

Comment: You'd have to show us how your define litems as you've not added that in the question.